# What are some good books of math applied to the military, warfare and combat.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, applications

Recently I've been interested in the math behind missiles, collisions, artilley, etc. I know topics like the parabolic course of a missile are in physics books, but I would like one that shows a variety of math applied to the military.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest studying number theory, since according to G.H.Hardy *No one has yet discovered any warlike purpose to be served by the theory of numbers or relativity, and it seems unlikely that anyone will do so for many years*.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Cryptography, which is related to number theory, is likely important in military intelligence/spying.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio General Relativity is used in the satellites. In particular, without relativity GPS yields errors of kilometers. Once it's taking into account, the error is the order of centimeters.

Comment: You might try searching for "weaponeering" on Amazon.